# Remap Port 443 to something else on localhost in Windows

Tags: windows, azure

I am trying to run Windows Azure Emulator on my localhost. My Access control service on emulator is located on port 8444. I want that whenever i access .accesscontrol.windows.net:443 on my localhost, i get redirected to 127.0.0.1:8444. I am able to redirect to 127.0.0.1 using c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file. How do i remap port 443 to 8444 on localhost

Comment: Why not access it directly via accesscontrol.windows.net:8444?

Comment: While deploying anything on azure emulator via UI, it tries to access <namespace>.accesscontrol.windows.net:443 by default

Answer (score 1):

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 ^
      listenport=443 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 ^
      connectport=8444 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```